# Creating a Modular Bowling Scores Program in Python3

Tags: python

In my beginner programming class I have a project where I am supposed to create a modular bowling score program. Here are the instructions:

"Functions should be invoked as necessary from the main program or from other functions. Your program should pass data around between functions as required, via arguments / parameters / return statements. Do not use global variables.

Your program should contain, at minimum, six separate functions that perform each of the following actions, and include the following characteristics:

- A main function
- Accept user information input
- Include sensible prompts / pay attention to the UI / UX
- Create the user's username (this function does not print anything)
- Accept score input
- Use a loop to accept an unknown number of score inputs until some sentinel value is entered
- Store the score inputs in a data structure / container, e.g. a list
- Determine skill level (this function does not print anything)
- Produce output
- Output the username, highest score, lowest score, average score, and skill level
- Once again, design your application's output with the UI / UX in mind"

I ran in to a problem trying to display the information. When I run the program the interpreter displays the username as the bowling scores instead of the actual scores and then gives me an error stating: "TypeError: unsupported format string passed to list.**format**" I also run into another issue where when I try to display highest_score it just says unexpected argument but I am unsure why. It does not do this for lowest_score even though the code seems very similar to me.

This is my code:

```
def getInput():
    scores = []
    score = int(input("Please enter a bowling score (-1 to exit): "))
    while score != -1:
        while score < 0 or score > 300:
            score = int(input("Please enter a VALID bowling score (0 through 300): "))
        scores.append(score)
        print("Score " + str(score) + " accepted.")
        score = int(input("Please enter another score (-1 to exit): "))
    return scores


def createUsername():
    firstname = input("Please enter your first name ")
    lastname = input("Please enter your last name ")
    age = input("How old are you? ")
    username = (firstname[0] + lastname + age)
    username_lowercase = username.lower()
    return username_lowercase


def calculateAverage(scores):
    average = sum(scores) / len(scores)
    return average


def skillLevel(average):
    if 0 < average <= 90:
        print('Your skill level is Beginner.')
    elif average <= 180:
        print('Your skill level is Intermediate.')
    else:
        print('Your skill level is Advanced.')


def lowest_scores(scores):
    lowest_score = min(scores)
    return lowest_score


def highest_scores(scores):
    highest_score = max(scores)
    return highest_score


def displayResults(scores, average, lowest_score, highest_score):
    print("You bowled the following scores: ")
    for s in scores:
        print(str(s))
    print("Your bowling average is {:.0f}".format(average))
    print("Your lowest score is " + str(lowest_score))
    print("Your highest score is " + str(highest_score))


bowlingScores = getInput()
username = createUsername()
average = calculateAverage(bowlingScores)
lowest_score = lowest_scores(bowlingScores)
highest_score = highest_scores(bowlingScores)
displayResults(username, bowlingScores, average, lowest_score)
```

This is my code with the highest_score included in the displayResult. I omitted it before so I could try to figure out the username issue first.

```
displayResults(username, bowlingScores, average, lowest_score, highest_score)
```

I am not even sure what to try because I don't know why the interpreter is taking the username and displaying it as a "list of scores" instead of using my actual list of scores. I've displayed the output below:

```
Please enter a bowling score (-1 to exit): 111
Score 111 accepted.
Please enter another score (-1 to exit): 222
Score 222 accepted.
Please enter another score (-1 to exit): 250
Score 250 accepted.
Please enter another score (-1 to exit): -1
Please enter your first name Tristen
Please enter your last name Roos
How old are you? 29
You bowled the following scores: 
t
r
o
o
s
2
9
```

Comment: You're passing the username to displayResults where you should be passing bowlingScores. Also, your code raises a TypeError